# How to make money with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, cryptocurrency

I have a couple 3Bs, and a 4B4.
The 3Bs are not in use now, so is there any way to make money with them?

- Selling them is not an option.
- Looking for a way to 'sell' their processing power over the internet, such as bitcoin, though I would prefer an alternative to bitcoin.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum, and questions like this don't work with the format.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.